# How to change Scene / Camera starting position in AndEngine GLES1.0

Tags: android, camera, andengine, scene

I am relatively new to AndEngine and stuck in one problem.
I made a really sample demo game, in which the character can move left and right in a game made of Tiled. By default, when the game starts, the scene/camera and character is placed at the left side of the screen. The camera moves from left edge of the screen to right side in Landscape mode.
Below is my working code:

```
private BoundCamera mCamera;
@Override
    public Engine onLoadEngine() {

        this.mCamera = new BoundCamera(-100, -100, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT){
            @Override
            public void onApplySceneMatrix(GL10 pGL) {
                    GLHelper.setProjectionIdentityMatrix(pGL);

                    GLU.gluOrtho2D(pGL, (int)this.getMinX(), (int)this.getMaxX(), (int)this.getMaxY(), (int)this.getMinY());
            }

        };

        final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT),
                mCamera);
        engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true);
        engineOptions.setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true);

        // It is necessary in a lot of applications to define the following
        // wake lock options in order to disable the device's display
        // from turning off during gameplay due to inactivity
        engineOptions.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);

        final Engine engine = new Engine(engineOptions);

        try {
            if (MultiTouch.isSupported(this)) {
                engine.setTouchController(new MultiTouchController());
                if (MultiTouch.isSupportedDistinct(this)) {

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "(MultiTouch detected, but your device might have problems to distinguish between separate fingers.)",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry your device does NOT support MultiTouch!\n\n(Falling back to SingleTouch.)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (final MultiTouchException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry your Android Version does NOT support MultiTouch!\n\n(Falling back to SingleTouch.)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return engine;
    }
```

I tried apply different values in `new BoundCamera()` constructor. But nothing works.
Please guide me to solve this. I want to start the camera and scene from the right edge of the screen in Landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

In need to make your camera to chase your player. You can do this by:

camera.setChaseEntity(player);

Just have a look at AndEngine Examples. It has an example which exactly serves your need. Follow the link below to download the code as well:

http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/

•TMXTiledMapExample

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I already have went through these examples. My camera chases the player correctly. What I want is just to initialize my scene and camera from the right edge of the screen instead of left edge, along with the player.

Comment: Ohh. okay. Sorry for misunderstanding your qustion.